# nginx access log read and write IO is too high

Tags: nginx

Nginx read and write IO is too high, check lsof |grep nginx, the access log is about 10G too large, and some deleted logs are still increasing. I can't find this log in Linux, but I can't find it on the nginx official website. View relevant information and ask for your help. Below is the deletion log viewed by lsof. This is certainly not nginx. The records at that time were not kept. Let me show you the relevant deleted pictures.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu6hc.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdguR.jpg)

Comment: Try to stop for a moment the Zabbix monitoring solution and see if there is still high IO.

Comment: It has nothing to do with zabbix, this screenshot is just for everyone to see what delete looks like

Comment: What is the traffic to NGINX? Do you have any log rotation configured? 10G sounds like no rotation exists. This wouldn't happen with a packaged install. Have you custom compiled NGINX?

Comment: I compiled it by myself, the log is not cut, and the traffic is 12G (Bytes)